# CSV file cleanup in bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a CSV file delimited with ',' which I'd like to use for further processing in a postgres db but not all lines have the correct number of columns.

I'm looking into a way of deleting all lines which don't have a specified number (15) of delimiters.

I've seen a lot of sed/awk solutions but none that would quite achieve what I need. Thanks!

Comment: try `awk -F, 'NF==15' file.csv`

Comment: @Sundeep : those damn off-by-one errors ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil yeah... should have been `NF==16` if number of delimiters required is `15`.. confused it with number of fields...

Comment: Thank you! I've tried all below solutions one by one and all worked :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -v FS=',' 'NF==16' <csv>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Perl one-liner to process the file:

`$ perl -lane '$c = $_ =~ tr/,//; print $_ if $c == 14' input_file.csv > output_file.csv`

This will read all lines from `input_file.csv` and if a line contains 15 commas it will print the line to `output_file.csv`

Comment: why not a simpler `perl -F, -ane 'print if $#F == 14'`

Comment: TIMTOWTDI :) Definitely will work too and will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work :

```
grep -e '^[^,]*\(,[^,]*\)\{15\}$' data.csv
```

Or with ruby :

```
ruby -ne 'print if $_.count(",")==15' < data.csv
```

Comment: can also use `-x` option to specify line match instead of `^$`

Answer (score 0):

In awk. Replace `,` with another `,`, count the number of subtitutions and print the ones with right amount:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/,/,",")==15' file
```

Ast there was no test data, there is no output. You just gotta trust me.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'NF!=16' file
```

more characters.

Comment: This one actually prints out all rows I don't want, but that can be handy, too. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah when you use double negatives in your requirements `**deleting** all lines which **don't** have a specified number (15) of delimiters` and don't show sample input/output it's easy to confuse us. If you wrote your requirements in a positive way (`print all lines that have a specified number (15) of delimiters`) then it would've been much less confusing and if you'd included sample input/output there would have been no chance of confusion at all.